# PHP server to server daily file transfer

Tags: php, security, file, transfer

I need a way of transferring the latest in a list of files from one server to another, and (if possible) replacing the file from the previous days transfer.

I.e. I have this image file on a secured server "http://username:password@mysite.com/image-22-2.png" (where 22-2 represents day-month) which is automattically transfered to a non-secure server.

The next day this file is uploaded onto the secure server "http://username:password@mysite.com/image-23-2.png" and I need "image-22-2.png" to be deleted and "image-23-2.png" to replace it.

Comment: This should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using `rsync` if your host permits it

Comment: rsync is a tool that you can call from the command line, for example `rsync -azvr /path/to/dir/ user@remotehost.tld:/path/to/dir/on/remote/host/` . You can put this in a cron job to be executed periodically (and use public/private keys for authentication). a nice tutorial for this setup can be read [here](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your host doesn't permit using `rsync`, you could set up a `cron` job with a scripted `ftp` transfer.